# How to reliably determine all folders not used in last 7 days?

Tags: bash, find, archive, cleanup

I'm writing a script for cleanup job. The script needs to cleanup all folders which are not accessed for more than 7 days. Currently I'm using -

```
for sub_folder in * ; do
   if [ -z $(find $sub_folder -type f -atime +7| head -n 1) ]; then
     rm -rf $sub_folder
   fi
done
```

Is there any better way which can reliably determine folders not used for last N days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the following script is better:

> Note: Pay attention to `rm` command! Use `echo "rm -rf $sub_folder"` for testing.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ];then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` DIRECTORY"
  exit 1
fi

for sub_folder in `find $@ -type d -atime +7 2>/dev/null` ; do
     rm -rf $sub_folder
done

exit 0
```

Comment: Just tested that, it doesn't work! Returns nothing but, I'm sure that there are lot of folders not used in last 7 days. :(

Comment: Well, I tested and is working for sure. Try to reduce the value for  `-atime`. You can test also with `-amin n` (file was last accessed n minutes ago.)

Comment: @Mayur If you have doubts, using `stat directory` command you can find last access time for `directory`.

Comment: worked. Tweaked a bit -

`for sub_folder in \`find $dir -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +$age 2>/dev/null\` ; do rm -rf $sub_folder; done`